# Is there a way to skip serialization in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 3.1 application, I need to read the raw data of a field, without serialization, and then write it down without serialization. Is this possible? How?

By serialization I mean

```
class Tenant
  serialize :profile_template
end
```

I obviously can access the field like this:

```
> t.profile_template
 => [{:title=>"Page 1", ....}]
```

I then also tried with read_attribute_before_type_cast (as per lucapette's suggestion):

```
> t.read_attribute_before_type_cast(:profile_template)
 => nil
```

Using a string instead of a symbol had a different but disappointing result:

```
> t.read_attribute_before_type_cast("profile_template")
 => [{:title=>"Page 1", ...}]
```

and same with the attribute name:

```
> t.profile_template_before_type_cast
 => [{:title=>"Page 1", ...}]
```

Just for the record, what I was expecting is:

```
"---
- :title: Page 1
...."
```

In all samples, ... is the rest of a very long structure.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way. You have to use

```
read_attribute_before_type_cast(:foo)
```

where :foo is the name of the field. The [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html) is not that good about that but I remember that there is a good explanation about it in The Rails 3 way.

*EDIT*

Although you're saying that this way isn't working for you I re-read the piece of information from the above-mentioned book. Well, there's another way of doing that. You can use

```
bar = foo_before_type_cast
```

where foo is the name of the field. It works like magic finders, pre-pending the name of the field to **_before_type_cast** . I can't try it right now but it really should work fine.

Comment: I tried that, but it returns nil for me. I'll amend the question.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Unfortunately I can't try now, I'll be able to do a test this evening if it can help.

Comment: I just tried it... it gives the de-serialized version instead of the string. I'll update the answer accordingly. Thank you for looking into this :)